# Simple MySQL query without using "ID" to create page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website that is database-driven.  I have created a static HTML page that contains a simple PHP query to fill in data from the database.

I created the static page, which is /artist-details.php

Then I added this query code to the page (along with some basic php variables to pull data)

```
<?php
@extract($_GET);
// connect to database
$hostname_site = "localhost";
$database_site = "xxxxx";
$username_site = "xxxxx";
$password_site = "xxxxxxxx";
$site = mysql_pconnect($hostname_site, $username_site, $password_site) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_site, $site);
$query = "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE ID = $ID";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
```

Now I can pull up a nice database-driven page when I use the URL 
/artist-details.php?ID=1

What I cannot figure out, even though it should be simple to do, is how to substitute "ID" and its number so that is something else, such as "art" so the URL is /artist-details.php?art=ArtistName or whatever.  Instead of querying the ID number, I want to query by something else using a URL.

I've searched for two hours and have come close, but I just can't get it.  It's frustrating because I know it's simple to do but nothing is working.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And if you want to handle multiple types of inputs, you'll have to TEST for each of those inputs, e.g. http://php.net/if

Comment: how about a form, a submit, and [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Then `mysqli` or `PDO` with Prepared Stmts?

Comment: This is frustrating because my question is NOT a duplicate to the one you linked. The one you linked is not what I'm looking for at all.

Comment: The PHP `mysql_` extension has been deprecated for a long time, and is dropped in the most recent versions of PHP. Use mysqli or PDO instead. And both of those extensions support prepared statements with bind placeholders. As Marc B indicated, you will need to add PHP code that figures out if you got an `art`...  `$_GET['art']` and what value(s) are associated with it. If you want to use those values in a database query, you'll need a different (or modified) SQL query.